# Difference between parseInt($(window).width()) and parseInt($(window).width) in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Difference between

> parseInt($(window).width())

and

> parseInt($(window).width)

in jquery?

Comment: - `.width()` is a jquery function that will get the width of an element/document. 
 - `.width`  is a javascript HTML DOM element property that will also return the width of an element/document. They are the same but, .width is already deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/width#Specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parseInt($(window).width())
```

will return the width of window

```
parseInt($(window).width)
```

will return NaN cause `$(window).width` will return the function instead of calling it -> and parsing a function to an int will return NaN

`$('.your-element').width` = the function to get/set the width of an object
`$('.your-element').width()` = call the function and get its return
`$('.your-element').width(100)` = set width property

Additionally to say -> jQuery will take care if u use `$().width()` and ur element is using border box -> it will subtract margin + border to calculate its correct width...
Further Infos:
[CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)
[CSS Box Sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?v=example)

Cheerio ;)